# How to redirect output to a file while creating tar in Solaris?

Tags: shell, pipe, io-redirection

I am creating a tar.gz file in Solaris using below command for redirecting output.

```
cd /ebs/datatop && tar cvf - * | gzip -c > /ebs/backup/proddata.tar.gz >> /dev/null 2>> error.log
```

When executed, it is creating `/ebs/backup/proddata.tar.gz` as an empty file. Does not give any errors. I am assuming tar files are being redirected to `/dev/null`. I want to redirect only the command output to `/dev/null` and write errors to error.log.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The output of `tar cvf -` is the archive. By specifying `-` as the argument to `f`, you're telling `tar` to output the archive on stdout (and in that case, because of the `|gzip`, `tar`'s stdout is a pipe to `gzip`).

The `v`erbose output (the list of files) which you asked for with `v` goes on stderr like error messages because it can't go on stdout as that would go to `gzip` and into the `tar.gz` file. Also note that your `2> error.log` only redirects `gzip`'s `stderr`.

If you don't want the verbose file list (what I assume you mean by *output*), then just omit the `v`. And redirect a subshell or command group's `stderr` if you want the error messages of all of `cd`, `tar` and `gzip` (and the shell's opening of the output file) to go to the log file:

```
(cd /ebs/datatop &&
   tar cf - . | gzip > /ebs/backup/proddata.tar.gz) 2>> error.log
```

I also replaced `*` with `.` to archive the current directory. `*` would only expand to the non-hidden files and would cause problems with some file names.

The `error.log` will be stored in the current working directory prior to that `cd`. In your approach, that `error.log` would have ended up being stored in the `tar.gz` file.

If you wanted to redirect that file list (with `v` or `vv`) to some file, and the errors to some other file, you'd need to use an argument other than `-` to the `f` flag. For instance using this syntax on systems with support for `/dev/fd/n`:

```
(tar cvvf /dev/fd/3 . 3>&1 > ../file.list | gzip > ../file.tar.gz) 2> ../error.log
```

Above, `/dev/fd/3` still refers to the pipe to `gzip` (as we've taken care of redirecting the file descriptor 3 to it (with `3>&1`) before redirecting stdout to `../file.list`), but since we're no longer telling `tar` to send the archive on its stdout, `tar` is free to write the file list on stdout (which we redirect to `../file.list`).

Comment: Does Solaris `tar` support multiple `v` options?

Comment: @AndrewHenle, while it accepts as many `v` as you'd like, that doesn't change the output (same ouput for `vv`, `v`, `vvv`...). So yes, you're right `cvvf` is not useful there unless you have GNU `tar`, `star`, or `bsdtar` available. Solaris `tar` still has a different output between `tar tf` and `tar tvf` though.